# CORONA SDK Display Text With Timer to synch with music

Tags: text, sdk, timer, coronasdk

I am quite new with programing and I am trying to understand how to display a text or update it on a specific time in corona SDK.

This is for a musical apllication, and I want the text to appear synched with the music, much like a karaoke but more simple. Just to display a sentence of the lyrics, and then replace it with the next at a specific time.
Also I wish that if the user replay the sound the timer restart to 0 so that the text and music would be still synched

Please advise me if you how to do it. I am really struggling to understand how to do it

Thank you !

Comment: What have you already tried to resolve the problem on your own?

Answer (score 1):

A simple timer with an array can be used to achieve what you want. 

The idea is to start a timer after a timer period right after the previous timer is triggered.

Check out the code below:

```
i = 2
--change the text to next line
function changeText( event )
    if i > #lyrics then
        timer.cancel(curTimer);
        print("timer destroyed")
    else
        print("lyrics[".. i .."]: "..lyrics[i].line)
        lyricsDisp.text = lyrics[i].line
        curTimer = timer.performWithDelay (lyrics[i].time, changeText,1)
    end
    i = i + 1
end

--initialize lyrics in an array
lyrics = {}
lyrics[1]        = {}
lyrics[1].line = "First line of song"
lyrics[1].time = 0
lyrics[2]  = {}
lyrics[2].line = "Second line of song"
lyrics[2].time = 2000
lyrics[3]      = {}
lyrics[3].line = "Third line of song"
lyrics[3].time = 5000
lyrics[4]      = {}
lyrics[4].line = "Fourth line of song"
lyrics[4].time = 1000
lyrics[5]      = {}
lyrics[5].line = "Fifth line of song"
lyrics[5].time = 3000

--restart song event handler
restartSong = function( self, event )
    if event.phase == 'ended' then
        timer.cancel(curTimer)
        lyricsDisp.text = lyrics[1].line
        i = 2
        curTimer = timer.performWithDelay(lyrics[i].time, changeText,1)
    end
end

--Initialize the lyrics text
lyricsDisp = display.newText(lyrics[i-1].line, 0, 0, native.systemFont,30)
lyricsDisp.x , lyricsDisp.y = display.contentWidth/2 , display.contentHeight/2

--start the lyrics timer
curTimer = timer.performWithDelay(lyrics[i].time, changeText,1)

--display object to restart the lyrics
restartText = display.newText("Reset", 0, 0, native.systemFont,30)
restartText.x , restartText.y = display.contentWidth/2 , display.contentHeight/2 + 200
restartText.touch = restartSong
restartText:addEventListener('touch', restartText)
```

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
local lyrics_label = display.newtext("This is my first line.... line 1",160,100,nil,15)

local lyrics_lines_array = {"This is my first line.... line 2",
                            "This is my second line.... line 3",
                            "This is my third line.... line 4",
                            "This is my fourth line.... line 5"}

local index = 0
local function textChange()
   index = index + 1
   lyrics_label.text = lyrics_lines_array[]
end
timer.performWithDelay(1000,textChange,#lyrics_lines_array)
             --[[ here 1000 ==> the time/delay to change the text ]]--
```